# Accessing Android Shared Preferences with MAUI Preview

Tags: .net-core, maui

**Background:**
I'm doing some work in MAUI preview to see if, upon full release, the features we need will be present. One of the things we will need for certain is the ability to read existing settings from our Xamarin apps. Our Xamarin app is aging, and it does need to be replaced in the next year or two.

**The core issue:**
We used the following code to fetch Android shared preferences in one of our Xamarin applications.

```
ISharedPreferences registrationSharedPref = GetSharedPreferences("Registration", Android.Content.FileCreationMode.Private);
registrationKey = registrationSharedPref.GetString("RegistrationKey", "");
```

How would I go about getting these settings with an MAUI app I plan to replace the existing one with?

The documentation is still spotty on this so anything that could point me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: "> The documentation is still spotty" if you can't find something in the .NET MAUI Docs, search the Xamarin.Forms or Xamarin.Essentials Docs and it should be very translatable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @ToolmakerSteve already pointed out, if this is Android specific code you want to use, place it in the Platforms\Android folder. Read more about the code sharing strategies in the .NET MAUI Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/invoke-platform-code

However, this shouldn't be Android specific code, depending on your actual needs. There is also the Preferences API in Essentials. This uses, in fact, the Android Shared Preferences. You can find all the info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/essentials/preferences

Note, the documentation is about Xamarin.Essentials, but all APIs are ported to .NET MAUI as well.

Comment: Ahh, partial classes. Much more convenient than the need to use DependencyService in Xamarin Forms. I hadn't seen that page yet; now I know what to refer to.

Comment: Yep there is actually quite some good stuff in the docs already and more on its way!

Comment: Thank you both for the responses. I think I'll attempt to mess with the Essentials API. The project we have was once two separate apps. The settings have slightly different names as such. I know essentials lets me run a platform specific query, from my forms experience, so I'll plug that in and query for the different settings values for each platform. 

I'm just now getting started with MAUI and wasn't sure how much of Forms directly translates into MAUI just yet. Seems like it may be quite a bit of it.